# Make GraphQL query or mutation arguments a bit more DRY

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

Using React and Apollo I have a mutation like this:

```
    const UPDATE_USER = gql`
        mutation UpdateUser($id: ID!, $someValue: String!, $someOtherValue: String!) {
            updateUser(id: $id, someValue: $someValue, someOtherValue: $someOtherValue) {
                id
                name
            }
        }
    `;

    const [mutateUser] = useMutation(UPDATE_USER, {
        variables: { id: 123, someValue: 'Hello', someOtherValue: 'World' },
    });
```

Works perfectly but the `UpdateUser` mutation is now just passing on arguments which doesn't seem very DRY to me.
I'm wondering if there is a way to shorten the code or make it a bit more manageable so that when another argument is added for example I don't have to retype it 4 times.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to the api, you can define it a little bit different:

```
const UPDATE_USER = gql`
    mutation UpdateUser($data: UpdateUserInput!) {
        updateUser(data: $UpdateUserInput) {
            id
            name
        }
    }
`;

const [mutateUser] = useMutation(UPDATE_USER, {
    variables: { data: { id: 123, someValue: 'Hello', someOtherValue: 'World' }},
});
```

Then in your api:

```
//User.type.js
//Note that this code depends on how you integrated your graphql solution. But the logic is here

const UpdateUserInputType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: "UpdateUserInput",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) },
    someValue: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    SomeOtherValue: { type: GraphQLString },
  }),
});
```

And then add UpdateUserInputType to your data arg at your resolver

Comment: I had hoped for a client side solution since it still feels like a lot of redundant code, but I guess this will have to do.